# Flask + RabbitMQ + SocketIO - forwarding messages

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, rabbitmq

I'm facing problem in emiting messages from RabbitMQ to User via SocketIO.

I have Flask application with [SocketIO integration](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO).
Current user flow seems like [image: this]

The problem is i'm not able to set up RabbitMQ listener which forward messages to browser via SocketIO. Every time i'm getting different error. Mostly is that connection is closed, or i'm working outside of application context.

I tried many approaches, here is my last one.

```
# callback 
def mq_listen(uid):
    rabbit = RabbitMQ()
    def cb(ch, method, properties, body, mq=rabbit):
        to_return = [0]  # mutable
        message = Message.load(body)
        to_return[0] = message.get_message()

        emit('report_part', {"data": to_return[0]})

    rabbit.listen('results', callback=cb, id=uid)

# this is the page, which user reach
@blueprint.route('/report_result/<uid>', methods=['GET'])
def report_result(uid):

    thread = threading.Thread(target=mq_listen, args=(uid,))
    thread.start()

     return render_template("property/report_result.html", socket_id=uid)
```

where rabbit.listen method is abstraction like:

```
def listen(self, queue_name, callback=None, id=None):
    if callback is not None:
        callback_function = callback
    else:
        callback_function = self.__callback
    if id is None:
        self.channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=True)
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.consumer_tag = self.channel.basic_consume(callback_function, queue=queue_name)
        self.channel.start_consuming()
    else:
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange=queue_name, type='direct')
        result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
        exchange_name = result.method.queue
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange=queue_name, queue=exchange_name, routing_key=id)
        self.channel.basic_consume(callback_function, queue=exchange_name, no_ack=True)
        self.channel.start_consuming()
```

which resulted into

```
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

I will be happy for any tip or example of usage.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't have direct answer for what you've included (nice diagram though) - but I've run into the "outside of request context" thing before, and it was typically a problem with (1) trying to call flask-using functions outside of the flask API, which meant the flask parts had to be factored out of the function, or (2) a callback which needed to be set up with data extracted from flask so that flask would be needed when the callback fired later or (3) some other chain of calls that dropped the flask context and failed to pass along the datum that was needed.  Not sure if that'll help though. :-/

Comment: I don't see it in your example, but have you created an application context?
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context?  You need to have the context pushed when you run outside of a request.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in the end of the day it's because when you make a request flask passes the request context to client. But the solution is NOT to add with app.app_context(). That is hackey and will definitely have errors as you're not natively sending the request context.

My solution was to create a redirect so that the request context is maintained like:

```
def sendToRedisFeed(eventPerson, type):
    eventPerson['type'] = type
    requests.get('http://localhost:5012/zmq-redirect', json=eventPerson)
```

This is my redirect function, so whenever there is an event I'd like to push to my PubSub it goes through this function, which then pushes to that localhost endpoint.

```
from flask_sse import sse

app.register_blueprint(sse, url_prefix='/stream')

@app.route('/zmq-redirect', methods=['GET'])
def send_message():
    try:
        sse.publish(request.get_json(), type='greeting')
        return Response('Sent!', mimetype="text/event-stream")

    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        pass
```

Now, whenever an event is pushed to my /zmq-redirect endpoint, it is redirected and published via SSE.

And now finally, just to wrap everything up, the client:

```
var source = new EventSource("/stream");

source.addEventListener(
  "greeting",
  function(event) {
    console.log(event)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that it's a Flask issue. While handling requests, Flask sets a context, but because you're using threads this context is lost. By the time it's needed, it is no longer available, so Flask gives the "working outside of request context" error.

A common way to resolve this is to provide the context manually. There is a section about this in the documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#manually-push-a-context

Your code doesn't show the socketio part. But I wonder if using something like flask-socketio could simplify some stuff... (https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I would open up the RabbitMQ connection in the background (preferably once) and use the `emit` function to send any updates to connected SocketIO clients.